# Unable to set cookies in electron

Tags: angular, cookies, electron

I'm trying to set cookies in electron but keep get error like insufficient  number of arguments while try to run the build,
thus arguments pass to cookies.set() and therefore, the cookies never set

```
  const { session } = require('electron')
  session.defaultSession.cookies.set({
   url: 'http://localhost/4200', 
   name:'dummy_name', value: 'dummy', 
   domain:'localhost', expirationDate: 99999999 
 })
 .then(() => {
    // success
 }, (error) => {
   console.error(error)
})
```

Comment: have you found solution to this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Yes Arshad. My initial problem was that i tried to run angular from the dist folder generated by ng build by adding the line win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/front/index.html`). Now the app open quite ok but it load from the index.html from the file system instead of of the server (Express) which i run from a separate directory from the angular app, thus no http request to allow the browser to set headers for cookies.

Comment: To solve this, i had to move the dist folder to server folder and change the content of my main.js from win.loadURL(file://${__dirname}/dist/front/index.html) to win.loadURL(http://localhost:5000) and added app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist','front'))) app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist','front','index.html'));
}). Now when i run npm run electron . it opens the app and load index.html from the dist/front folder on the server thus making http request and setting cookies headers accordingly. i uses ngx-cookie package to set cookies in Angular